# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required in XAMPP

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

It getting following errors.

> Warning: require(validation_functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\validation_errors.php on line 11
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'validation_functions.php' (include_path='.;c:\php\includes;') in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\validation_errors.php on line 11

I already find the solution but not properly get it.

```
getcwd(); -> C:\xampp\htdocs\practice
```

and

```
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]; -> C:/xampp/htdocs
```

Comment: Where does `validation_functions.php` exists in your file structure?

Comment: validation_functions.php should be placed with validation_errors.php file

Comment: both are in /htdocs/practice folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing file name as a string to `require()` function.

Try like this:

```
require("validation_functions.php");
```